# Getting windows caption from process ID

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I have a process ID, what I want to do is return the class.  If it is the desired class then return the caption, how do I do that?

C Visual Studio 2008, XP SP3

Comment: Are you trying to find the caption of the title window? The name of the EXE.  The windows Class?  Are you looking for the jabberwocky.

Comment: No, surprisingly I found the jabberwocky and he won't stop eating my biscuits.  I am after the window class, and then the caption.

Comment: rule #1: Don't look for the jabberwocky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) with [GetWindowThreadProcessID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) to find the HWND with the matching process ID that you're looking for.

Once you have the HWND you can use [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(VS.85).aspx) to get the class name.

Once you have the HWND with the class you want you can use either:

- [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) to send a [WM_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627(VS.85).aspx).
- Or [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx)

Read [Raymond Chen's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx) here on the differences.

Comment: I actually managed to do that and EnumWindows worked like a champ...  Thanks :)